# Read from a testnet Rinkeby contract with hardhat script

Tags: javascript, testnets, rinkeby, hardhat, web3-providers

I am trying to read state variables (using hardhat scripts) from a contract deployed on the Rinkeby network.
I use the script below but it returns 'undefined' as if it can't read from the contract.

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  const abi = [ { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "previousOwner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" } ], "name": "OwnershipTransferred", "type": "event" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "owner", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "renounceOwnership", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" } ], "name": "transferOwnership", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" } ];
  
  let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('rinkeby');


  const designManager = await new ethers.Contract(0x60D70e76eF9158F1bBDC829f4b3CbabeAadF0F86, abi, provider);

  const projectName1 = await designManager.projectName;

  console.log(projectName1);
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

When I run the script using `npx hardhat run scripts/logs.js --network rinkeby` I am getting the terminal output:
`undefined`
Could you please advise what is wrong in my script?